# What are the use cases of multilevel Symbols?

Tags: dart

**Glossary**: What I mean by multilevel Symbol is something that is like #Dummy.bar instead of single level like #bar. Dont know what is better name for it, sorry.

Symbols are very nifty. I can do:

```dart
class Foo {
 static String hello() => "Said hello!";
}

ClassMirror clMir = reflectType(Foo) as ClassMirror();
print(clMir.invoke(#hello, []));
```

It prints *Said hello!*. Great!

But one cant do:

```dart
class Bar{
 static final Bar bar = new Bar();
}

ClassMirror clMir = reflectType(Bar) as ClassMirror();
print(clMir.invoke(#bar.hello, []));
```

This would fail.

Also, I haven't found a place where you can get reflection for multilevel Symbol, like `reflectSymbol(#Dummy.bar)` and get InstanceMirror for bar or something similar.

So are there use cases for multilevel Symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different use-cases.
Primarily, it represents a library name (`library foo.bar.baz;`). The mirror system uses it for that (see, e.g., https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.20.1/dart-mirrors/MirrorSystem/findLibrary.html).

Secondarily, the mirror system is sometimes using it as a "qualified name" like `library.name.ClassName.memberName` to represent an exact class or library member (https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.20.1/dart-mirrors/DeclarationMirror/qualifiedName.html).

It's not that useful outside of the mirror system.

Comment: Thanks.

I wish Dart symbol literals are more powerful that they can be code completed, analyzer checked and also refactored.

Comment: Symbols are just dumb data, so completing them isn't really viable, not more than completing string content is. Most people shouldn't use them for anything (based on the assumption that most people shouldn't use reflection, and if you don't use reflection, you shouldn't need symbols). The `Function.apply` function and the `noSuchMethod` `Invocation` argument are reflective functions that are outside the mirrors library, and where you are most likely to encounter symbols as a normal user.

Comment: I dont like to use mirrors when it is not necessary. But i think Symbols have a very good use case in annotations. 

1. In source generation to refer to members, etc.

2. In angular to bind, etc

Generally Strings are used in these cases. If Symbol literals support presence detection by analyzer, code completion by IDEs/analyzer and refractoring by IDEs/dart tools, it would be a big plus.

For example:

    class User {
      String name;
    }

    @EncodeField(#User.name, as: 'Name')
    class Serializer implements MapSerializer<User> {
      ...
    }